# Cookie shows in callback url, but not in browser cookie storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, cookies, passport.js

I am trying to save the `facebookPicUrl` pic in a cookie. I see it in the callback request, but I don't see it in the cookie storage of the browser. Just to be clear, the session cookie has no issues.

```
auth.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, userDoc, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      // I don't think !userDoc will ever happen because of mongo upsert
      if (!userDoc) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
      res.cookie('facebookPicUrl', userDoc.value.facebook.picture, {maxAge : 99999,
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: false,
      signed: false
      });
      res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:9000/users')
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Here it is in the callback url:

[image]

But not in the cookie storage:

[image]

Comment: I saw expire of cookie facebookPicUrl is about 1.6 min in the first image. Maybe the cookie is already expired and deleted automatically by browser! I also saw the request cookie contains facebookPicUrl. This means, the browser did store your facebookPicUrl cookie before. So I assume your facebookPicUrl cookie is expired. Could you increase the expired time?

Comment: naw, I checked right afterwards....well with in the 1.6 min. Also, I changed the cookie time to 2.8 hours and it's still not showing up.

Comment: As this cookie is not httpOnly, can we run document.cookie in Chrome console to check what is output.

Comment: correct, it only shows the session cookie...the `facebookPicUrl` cookie is not there.

Comment: Interesting, maybe facebookPicUrl is removed from some other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:9000/users')` is a hardcoded value, guessing that the `req.headers.host` does not match `'127.0.0.1'`